# changing Tone.js sequencer events dynamically

Tags: javascript, tonejs

I want to change the Sequencer Object's events array while it is playing.
The following code is from [Tone.js Sequencer](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/Sequence) Page.

```
const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination()
const seq = new Tone.Sequence((time, note) => {
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, .1, time)
}, ["C4", ["E4", "D4", "E4"], "G4", ["A4", "G4"]] /*I wanna change this arr*/).start(0)
```

I am a bit lost, to be honest. In the seq Object, there is a property called

```
Tone.Sequencer._events
```

And underneath the `_events` there are handlers that called get and set, but when I checked the source

```
private _createSequence(array: any[]): any[] {
        return new Proxy(array, {
            get: (target: any[], property: PropertyKey): any => {
                // property is index in this case
                return target[property];
            },
            set: (target: any[], property: PropertyKey, value: any): boolean => {
                if (isString(property) && isFinite(parseInt(property, 10))) {
                    if (isArray(value)) {
                        target[property] = this._createSequence(value);
                    } else {
                        target[property] = value;
                    }
                } else {
                    target[property] = value;
                }
                this._eventsUpdated();
                // return true to accept the changes
                return true;
            },
        });
    }
```

And I decided, I could use a little help at this point. Is there any way to change/replace the array that is playing without stopping the Tone.Transport?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this issue:
I am not equipped to give any extra information about the Proxy Arrays in JavaScript, but [here is a simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) start.

```
const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination()
const seq = new Tone.Sequence((time, note) => {
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, .1, time)
}, ["C4", ["E4", "D4", "E4"], "G4", ["A4", "G4"]] /*I wanna change this arr*/).start(0)

const eventArray = seq._events // this points to seq._eventsArray

eventArray.push("D4") // allowing array operations
eventArray[n] = ["F3", "G#3"]
eventArray.splice(0, n) // etc...

seq._eventsUpdated() // forces to update the array
```

However, note that this solution did not satisfy my requirements, the changes do not affect the array immediately but happen sometime after. The technical side is beyond my knowledge to explain or use exact jargon that is related to the issue. sorry about this. But as another solution, I have created my sequencer with using basic javascript `setInterval` and `setTimeout` methods.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).